# Time complexity problem

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, algorithm-analysis

Let Σ = {0, 1} and let A ⊆ Σ<sup>*</sup> be a language contained in DTIME(4<sup>n</sup>), and define

B = {xx | x ∈ A}.

(a) Show that B ∈ DTIME(2<sup>n</sup>).

(b) Prove that  A ≤<sup>p</sup><sub>m</sub> B.

I'm new to complexity theory. how can I show that if the language has the time complexity O(4<sup>n</sup>) how can i got about proving that its sublanguage has the complexity O(2<sup>n</sup>). also any help with the part(b) would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By hypothesis there is a Turing machine $T$ that decides $A$ in time $O(4^n)$.

Regarding a): you can design a Turing machine $T'$ that given $x$ operates as follows:

- First, it computes $|x|$ (i.e., $n$) in time $O(n)$. If $|x|$ is odd it rejects.
- If $|x|$ is even, it simulates $T$ on the input $y$ of consisting of the first $\frac{|x|}{2}$ characters of $|x|$. $T'$ accepts if $T(y)$ accepts and rejects otherwise. Simulating $T(y)$ takes time $O(4^\frac{|x|}{2}) = O(2^n)$.

Regarding b): Given  $x \in \Sigma^*$ it suffices to consider $y=xx$. It is easy to see that $y$ can be constructed in polynomial time and that $x \in A \iff y \in B$.